# Can someone please explain this limit

Tags: limits

According to my math textbook $\int \limits _0 ^\infty \ln \left| \dfrac {x+1} {x+2} \right| \Bbb d x = \ln 2$. I don't understand how the limit of $\lim \limits _{x \to \infty} \ln \left| \dfrac {x+1} {x+2} \right| = 0$. I cannot find any explanation in the textbook.

Comment: Do you mean $\ln |x+\frac{1}{x}+2|$?

Comment: See Mike's answer. Brackets are important.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with improper integrals, it is only about the limit of a continuous function.

Answer (score 1):

$$
  \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right) = 
  \ln\left(\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x+1}{x+2}\right) = 
  \ln(1) = 0
$$

Comment: One small point, you can bring the limit inside the $\ln$ because it is a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, the following steps $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln\left|\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right|=\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln\left|\frac{x\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)}\right|=\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln\left|\frac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{1+\frac{2}{x}}\right|=\ln\left|\frac{1+0}{1+0}\right|=\ln|1|=0$$